# How to truncate seconds from a column (timestamp) in PostgreSQL without using date_trunc function

Tags: datetime, postgresql-9.3

I am using **PostgreSQL 9.3.19**, earlier I have made the following Query

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('minute', some_date) FROM some_table;
```

This was working fine but I got to know that index made on **some_date** column will be futile because indexes doesn't work with **DATE_TRUNC()**, Index created was as follows :

`CREATE INDEX ON some_table USING BTREE(DATE_TRUNC('minute', some_date));`

So is there any other way to truncate seconds without affecting my present Index and without using **DATE_TRUNC** in **PostgreSQL 9.3.19** ?

Comment: No I am not allowed to change the working Index. I want some other way to truncate seconds @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: So if you have the index, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Read the above question again @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I did, and I don't understand it. What is the problem with the query you have? Does it throw an error? If yes, [edit] your question and add the exact error message. If it doesn't throw an error but returns the wrong data, then you need to explain what input data you have and what you expect from the query.

Comment: If it is a performance problem then **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT date_trunc('seconds', '2021-12-28 14:00:03.933438'::timestamp);
-- RESULT 2021-12-28 14:00:03
```

[as here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date_trunc/)

Comment: It looks like your answer is just what original author of the question was not looking for. Please look at the question again.